# Magnification of an object at focal point

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Why do I see an image when I place an object at a focal point of a lens? I've been tinkering around with a simple concave lens and my phone's LED. The lens has a focal length of about 5cm. When I place my LED light at approximately 5cm of the lens I'm able to see an image at any plane. Whether I point it to a wall near me or to a wall farther away, I always see a sharp image of the LED (considering my hand shaking but still...). Why do I see this image? Shouldn't I need to focus an object on a focal plane (through the thin lens equation $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{f}$? I think I'm confused in "what does the eye need to see an image?"

Comment: When you say you see the image, are you looking through the lens with your eye or projecting the image onto a piece of paper?

Comment: I'm projecting into a piece of paper or wall. The set up is my left hand holding the phone, and my right hand holding the lens about 5cm of the LED and I'm facing a wall and looking at the image on the wall.

Comment: One more question: At first glance this seems like a depth of field question, and DoF depends on the aperture. (For example, a pinhole camera works without a lens because a tiny aperture has an very large DoF -- and a single point has infinite DoF.) Is there an aperture, and and if not, what's the diameter of your lens?

Comment: Ah, I see where you're getting at. There's no aperture, and the diameter is quite small, 3cm, so the DoF will be quite large, and that sort of partly answers the question. But I still don't get what does the eye need to see an image? Along those lines it means that I was actually focusing the object on the wall

Comment: 1) 3cm is a large enough lens to need an aperture for a reasonable DoF in most cases so it's probably a misdirection (though I'm not used to the math of projecting onto a wall so i'd have to work it out to be sure). 2) I'm not sure what you mean by "what does the eye need to see an image?". Maybe you mean, can the eye resharpen an image? The eye can't sharpen an image after light directionality is lost (ie, after scattering of a wall or piece of paper).

Comment: What I mean for What dies the eye need is this: in this set up, suppose I focus the LED on the wall. That is, I place the Led a bit off the focal point. The object gets focused on the wall and I see the square led perfectly. Suppose now that, somehow, I'm able to place the led exactly at the focal point. Then I have parallel Ray's hitting the wall. Will I see an image? Or in other words, does my eye need parallel Ray's to see an image or does it need a focused image in front if me?